# How to delete duplicate files from a particular directory

Tags: java, duplicates

I want to count the no files in which a string is occurring and I have a list of documents in a directory but they are redundant. How do I remove the duplicate files from that particular directory?
Any help appreciated!

```
 public static boolean CompareFiles(File x, File y) throws FileNotFoundException 
 { //boolean result=true;

    try     {
       Scanner xs = new Scanner(x);
       Scanner ys = new Scanner(y);
       boolean result = true;
       while (result)
       {
           if (xs.nextByte() != ys.nextByte()) result = false;


       }

return result;
    }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return false;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException//     
    { 

    File dir = new File("C:/Users/Aravind/Documents/ranked");
    File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
    for (int x = 0; x <fileList.length; x++)
    {
    for (int y = x+1; y < fileList.length; y++)
    {
    if (CompareFiles(fileList[x],fileList[y])) 
    {
        System.out.println("in calling fn");
        fileList[x].delete();
    }
        //System.out.println(fileList[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create redundant files in single directory?

Comment: Do you mean files like `~somedoc.txt` that seem to be duplicates of `somedoc.txt` etc.? If so, just check whether the filename starts with `~` or not. Otherwise, please be more specific and maybe provide an example.

Comment: I am searching for a word in an index and based on that I am creating files in a directory, so there are redundant files. Ya  Imean the content of the file is redundant not the name of the file.

Comment: For example, I have three files ile1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt. Now suppose file1.txt and file2.txt has the same content in them and file3.txt has different content. I want to delete one of the file1.txt or file2.txt. How? in java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a map using the name of the file as key and the checksum of the file as value (follow this [example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0416.html) to get a file's checksum using java).

Before adding an new entry to that map, check if the calculated checksum already exists vith `containsValue` (if two files have the same checksum, their contents are the same).

Delete the "redundant" file.

Comment: If I have two files, one with the contents `"This is a file"` and another with the contents `"     This is a file"`, their checksums will be very different. Even though the data inside the files is identical.

Comment: Of course. In the 5th comment, Aravind Chinta said "the same content", so I assumed "exactly the same content", as he did not mention anything about heading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) if (isDuplicate(f)) f.delete();
```

... or maybe give us more details on what you need.

Comment: For example, I have three files ile1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt. Now suppose file1.txt and file2.txt has the same content in them and file3.txt has different content. I want to delete one of the file1.txt or file2.txt. How? in java

Comment: Can you load the complete contents of all files into ram? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No. Something to with the RAMDirectory?